# Pig - add jars to classpath

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Pig combines all the jars which are registered through (`pigserver.registerjar`) into a single job.jar. This actually removes the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`.

We have a UDF which looks for jar with `MANIFEST.MF` containing predefined properties (one of our jar contains this). As Pig removes this `MANIFEST.MF` our UDF stops working.

Is there a way to add the jar to classpath instead of registerjar? or Is there any way to overcome this?

Following is the code snippet:

```
cluster = new Cluster(new PigContext(ExecType.MAPREDUCE,properties));
PigServer pigServer = new PigServer(ExecType.MAPREDUCE,properties);
pigServer.registerJar("xyz.jar");
PigTest pigTest =  new PigTest(pigFile, args, pigServer, cluster);
pigTest.assertOutput("xxyyzz", jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the classpath from within your parent program which is submitting the Pig scripts or else even simpler would be to just
use a Unix script which sets the classpath just before executing the parent program, something like    `CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:your_jars java parent_program`
The above line will ensure that the CLASSPATH variable is modified just for the execution of current program

Answer (score 0):

add:

```
PIG_CLASSPATH=your_jar_file
```

to:

```
$PIG_HOME/bin/pig
```